# How to compute directed graph diameter in C++

Tags: c++, graph

I have a directed graph given by a matrix and I need to write a program (C++) that computes it's diameter. I'm really lost when it comes to this. Is there a known algorithm for this? \

How I think it should go:

- convert to undirected graph (for any directedMatrix[i][j] !=0 , with i from 1 to nrNodes and j from i+1 to nrNodes, make matrix[j][i]=matrix[i][j]=directedMatrix[i][j])
- compute max distance for any 2 nodes ( distaceMatrix[i][j] = max distance from node i to node j; distanceMatrix[i][i] = MIN)
- find the maxim value from the above matrix and that's our answer.

Thoughts and optimizations?

Comment: Have you tried to search for anything? Tried to implement any of the algorithms you found? What problem with this program do you have? You actually *have* tried something yourself first? You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Do you happen to know the maximal number of nodes that are going to be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number of nodes is not too great, a simple solution would be to use Floyd-Warshall algorithm to find the shortest paths between all pairs of nodes and then simply to take the greatest one. The following code demonstrates it:

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 107
#define NOT_CONNECTED -1

int distance[MAX][MAX];

//number of nodes
int nodesCount;

//initialize all distances to 
void Initialize(){
    for (int i=0;i<MAX;++i){
        for (int j=0;j<MAX;++j){
            distance[i][j]=NOT_CONNECTED;
        }
        distance[i][i]=0;
    }
}

int main(){

    Initialize();

    //get the nodes count
    scanf("%d", &nodesCount);

    //edges count
    int m;
    scanf("%d", &m);

    while(m--){
        //nodes - let the indexation begin from 1
        int a, b;

        //edge weight
        int c;

        scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
        distance[a][b]=c;
    }

    //Floyd-Warshall
    for (int k=1;k<=nodesCount;++k){
        for (int i=1;i<=nodesCount;++i){
            if (distance[i][k]!=NOT_CONNECTED){
                for (int j=1;j<=nodesCount;++j){
                    if (distance[k][j]!=NOT_CONNECTED && (distance[i][j]==NOT_CONNECTED || distance[i][k]+distance[k][j]<distance[i][j])){
                        distance[i][j]=distance[i][k]+distance[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int diameter=-1;

    //look for the most distant pair
    for (int i=1;i<=nodesCount;++i){
        for (int j=1;j<=nodesCount;++j){
            if (diameter<distance[i][j]){
                diameter=distance[i][j];
                printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", diameter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the diameter is maximum value from the shortest paths? I was assuming it is the longest path from any 2 nodes and that it only exists in graphs without cycles. Thank you for clearing this out.

Comment: @user3002428 Yes, that's how I understood the problem by reading Wikipedia. On the page Distance_(graph_theory) there are the following sentences: "To find the diameter of a graph, first find the shortest path between each pair of vertices. The greatest length of any of these paths is the diameter of the graph."

Comment: thanks. I found some contradictory definitions on the net and my teacher is one of those people who don't have a email address.