# Can we use the BFS on each vertex in order to find the graph's diameter? if so, is this the best solution?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

So i found an old topic :

[Algorithm for diameter of graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646307/algorithm-for-diameter-of-graph)

which they said the best solution for non sparse graph is O(V^3)

but can't we just use the BFS on each vertex and then find the maximum?
and this way the time complexity will be O(V*(V+E)) = O(V^2 + VE)
am i wrong? because if the number of edges is just a multiplicand of V then this would work better, right?

so i guess my question is :

1. **what is the best time complexity for computing the graph's diameter as of now in 2018**
2. **is my method wrong? what am i missing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix in question is **non-sparse**. So it gives a worst case E ~ (V^2)/2 edges. The solution mentioned will thus become O(V^2+V*(V^2)) for non-sparse matrixes.

If the matrix was sparse then it would indeed be faster than O(V^3).

Also given the graph is non-sparse, it is usually represented using adjacency matrix, for faster lookup times. Breadth First Search would thus take O(V^2). This done as you mentioned across all nodes will again lead to O(V^3) computational time complexity.

Finding the diameter can be done by finding all pair shortest paths first and determining the maximum length found. [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) does this in O(V^3) time. [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) can be implemented to achieve O(V^2 logV + VE) time.

Comment: So in case of sparse graphs, isn't the algorithm that i mentioned better than Johnson's algorithm? considering johnson is O(V^2 logV + VE) but the one i said is O(V^2 + VE)?