# Find the Diameter of an unweighted undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, pseudocode

The diameter as in, the largest minimum distance between any two points in the graph.

To solve this, would we just do BFS from any node, and then choose a node among the farthest nodes from the original node. Do BFS on this new node, and then the largest distance here is the diameter of the graph.

Another post talks about weighted directed graphs. This is strictly for unweighted. Although the same algorithm might work here, I am asking if we can do it more efficiently w/ the algo I proposed here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm for diameter of graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646307/algorithm-for-diameter-of-graph)

Comment: That is the other post that I mentioned in my post. I am asking specifically for an unweighted, undirected graph.

Answer (score 0):

[`diameter`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.distance_measures.diameter.html#networkx.algorithms.distance_measures.diameter) does exactly this.

```
G = nx.lollipop_graph(5, 5)
nx.diameter(G)
```

Output: `6`

Comment: I am not finding any pseudo code. Are you saying diameter does eccentricity(v) twice? i.e. BFS twice? So O(N)?

Comment: I'm not sure of the details beyond the documentation, which states eccentricity is calculated for each node in the graph and the maximum eccentricity value is returned as the diameter of the graph.

Comment: My question was if you can just do eccentricity twice and get the same result. Look at my question. I am not saying to do BFS max dist from all of the nodes, just 2.